# HP 2920 VLAN ACL's Configuration

Tags: hp, vlan, access-control-list

I have a HP 2920 with 5 VLAN's configured. I am in the process of configuring a Guest Wireless which will be used by visitors to our business. I have created a new VLAN for this with it's own subnet. What I am trying to figure out is the correct ACL's on the 2920 to allow their VLAN to go out to the gateway but not access any other VLAN's.

For the purposes of this the gateway is on VLAN 1 (192.168.1.200/24) and the new VLAN will be ID 200 (10.200.2.1/24). There are other devices on VLAN1 which I do not want the guests to be able to access, they just need to see the gateway.

I appreciate any help as my head hurts now from reading the HP docs!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Right now it's a little too broad.

Answer (score 0):

`I have created a new VLAN for this with it's own subnet` - `For the purposes of this the gateway is on VLAN 1 (192.168.1.200/24)` - Those statements contradict each other. A host can't use a Default Gateway that is on another network. What you need to do is to configure your router with an interface in each VLAN with an appropriate ip address for each subnet and use those interfaces as the DG for the hosts in each VLAN.

Comment: The HP 2920 is a layer 3 switch which is acting as the router between the VLANS, the default route from the 2920 points to the gateway on 192.168.1.200

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I'm referring to. Each subnet/network needs to have it's own local DG. You can do that with your router or with your Layer 3 switch. Inter-VLAN routing is certainly something you can do with the switch but each subnet/network that you configure for each VLAN needs it's own DG. Each VLAN interface needs an ip address which will then be used by the hosts in each VLAN as their DG.

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain that too well. The default gateway for the new VLAN will be 10.200.2.1. That VLAN need to be able to get to the internet via the main internet gateway on 192.168.1.200 buy does not need to access any other VLAN or devices on the 192.168.1.0 subnet. Hope that makes it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of trial and error managed to get a working setup. For anyone that's looking in future it looks like this:

```
ip access-list extended "WiFi Guest"
     10 permit ip 10.200.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.200 0.0.0.255 log
     20 deny ip 10.200.2.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 log
     30 permit ip 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
   exit

vlan 200 ip access-group "WiFi Guest" vlan-in
```